# VS 2008, ASP.NET: Generate Local Resources

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, designer

I've build an simple control called Menu:

```
namespace MyControls
{
    public class MenuItem
    {
        public MenuItem()
        {
            Visible = true;
        }

        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [Localizable(false)]
        public string Link { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool Visible { get; set; }
    }

    public class MenuDesigner : System.Web.UI.Design.ControlDesigner
    {
        ...
    }

    [ParseChildren(true, "Items")]
    [PersistChildren(false)]
    [Designer(typeof(MenuDesigner))]
    public class Menu : Control
    {
        ...

        public Menu()
        {
        }

        ...

        private List<MenuItem> _items = new List<MenuItem>();
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<MenuItem> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e); 

            ... // More Controls.

            list = new BulletedList();
            list.DisplayMode = BulletedListDisplayMode.HyperLink;
            this.Controls.Add(list);

            foreach (var mi in _items)
            {
                list.Items.Add(new ListItem(mi.Text, Page.Request.CreateUrl(mi.Link)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use it in my Page this way:

```
    <my:Menu ID="menu" runat="server" Text="MenuTitle">
        <my:MenuItem Text="text" Link="link1.aspx">
        </my:MenuItem>
        <my:MenuItem Text="text2" Link="link2.aspx">
        </my:MenuItem>
    </my:Menu>
```

This works. No Problems. When I switch to the Designer View I see the Control in the way my MenuDesigner renders it. Reformating with CTRL-K, CTRL-D works. Running my WebPage renders to Menu the way I expected it.

But: when I hit in the DesingView the Menu Item "Tools" -> "Generate Local Resource" I get this result:

```
<my:Menu ID="menu" runat="server" Text="MenuTitle" 
            meta:resourcekey="menuResource9">
            <my:MenuItem Text="text" Link="link1.aspx">
            </my:MenuItem>
            <my:MenuItem Text="text2" Link="link2.aspx">
            </my:MenuItem>
            <Items>
<my:MenuItem Text="text" Link="link1.aspx" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource10"></my:MenuItem>
<my:MenuItem Text="text2" Link="link2.aspx" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource11"></my:MenuItem>
</Items>
        </my:Menu>
```

Which Attributes are missing/wrong? I've looked into ListBox, which also parses child items an I have the feelding that my control is doing the same.

The only differences I've found:

- I am using a generic List, ListBox has it's own collection type for ListItems
- I have no Editor or ControlBuilder or TypeConverter for my MenuItem, ListBox does.

This is not a control I'm willing to sell, it's only for me. I don't need any Editor or Desinger, I'm writing HTML/ASP.NET markup by hand.

I am using Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5.

Thanks for any Hints, Help or Sulutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, your code is incorrect. Because, you didn't implement `IStateManager` in the `MenuItem`. Also generic list is not a valid type in this case. You have to write a custom collection that implements `IStateManager` or use `StateManagedCollection`.

**MenuItem**

```
public class MenuItem : IStateManager
{

    private StateBag _viewState;
    private bool _isTrackingViewState;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)ViewState["Text"] ?? string.Empty; }
        set { ViewState["Text"] = value; }
    }

    public void SetDirty()
    {
        if (this._viewState != null)
            this._viewState.SetDirty(true);
    }

    protected virtual StateBag ViewState
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._viewState == null)
            {
                this._viewState = new StateBag(true);
                if (this._isTrackingViewState)
                    ((IStateManager)this._viewState).TrackViewState();
            }
            return this._viewState;
        }
    }

    bool IStateManager.IsTrackingViewState
    {
        get { return this._isTrackingViewState; }
    }

    void IStateManager.LoadViewState(object state)
    {
        if (state != null)
            ((IStateManager)this.ViewState).LoadViewState(state);
    }

    object IStateManager.SaveViewState()
    {
        if (this._viewState != null)
            return ((IStateManager)this._viewState).SaveViewState();
        return null;
    }

    void IStateManager.TrackViewState()
    {
        this._isTrackingViewState = true;

        if (this._viewState != null)
            ((IStateManager)this._viewState).TrackViewState();
    }

}
```

**MenuItemCollection**

```
public class MenuItemCollection : StateManagedCollection
{

    public MenuItem this[int index]
    {
        get { return (MenuItem)((IList)this)[index]; }
    }

    public int Add(MenuItem item)
    {
        return ((IList)this).Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(MenuItem item)
    {
        ((IList)this).Remove(item);
    }

    // Write Insert and RemoveAt methods

    protected override void SetDirtyObject(object o)
    {
        ((MenuItem)o).SetDirty();
    }

}
```

**Menu**

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Items"), PersistChildren(false)]
public class Menu : Control
{

    private MenuItemCollection _items;

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty), MergableProperty(false)]
    public MenuItemCollection Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._items == null)
            {
                this._items = new MenuItemCollection();
                if (base.IsTrackingViewState)
                    ((IStateManager)this._items).TrackViewState();
            }
            return this._items;
        }
    }

    protected override void TrackViewState()
    {
        base.TrackViewState();

        if (this._items != null)
            ((IStateManager)this._items).TrackViewState();
    }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        Pair states = (Pair)savedState;

        base.LoadViewState(states.First);

        if (states.Second != null)
            ((IStateManager)this.Items).LoadViewState(states.Second);
    }

    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        Pair states = new Pair();

        states.First = base.SaveViewState();

        if (this._items != null)
            states.Second = ((IStateManager)this._items).SaveViewState();

        return states;
    }

}
```

**Note:** I didn't test the above code.

Anyway, there was another answer before mine that was correct in my opition, but has been deleted. You have set the `PersistenceMode` of `Items` property to `InnerProperty`. Thus, you have to write markup as follows.

```
<my:Menu ID="menu" runat="server" Text="MenuTitle">
    <Items>
        <my:MenuItem Text="text" Link="link1.aspx" />
        <my:MenuItem Text="text2" Link="link2.aspx" />
    </Items>
</my:Menu>
```

Comment: Yes! PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty did it! Thank you! BTW: I've tried to implement a StateManagedCollection but with no luck. OK - I stopped implementing StateManagedCollection when I read your Edit.

Comment: Oh man, I'm so sorry. This point is not mine. As far as I said other user answer your question. But, he deleted his post. Anyway, I'll write a simple example for you to fix the ViewState problem.

Comment: Thanks! In that case I do not need to fix the viewstate issue (not using viewstate) but I interesting in it! So: No stress!

Comment: @another users answer: Well, you saw that this might be the right direction, you saw that the post was deleted, you repeated it because you thought it may be right. So I think the points are yours :-)

Comment: @Mehdi Golchin, can I ask you a question? In your MenuItemCollection, if I want to use MenuItem and MenuItem2 class as well, how would I have to implement it?

Comment: @JoshuaSon, you have to derive both class from a base class (e.g. MenuItemBase).

Comment: Shouldn't it be if (this._items == null) and not if (this._items != null) in Menu: public MenuItemCollection Items?

Comment: @eithe, without doubt... Thanks :)