# multiple IStateManager in StateManagedCollection

Tags: asp.net

I was reading a post at [VS 2008, ASP.NET: Generate Local Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200321/vs-2008-asp-net-generate-local-resources).
Mehdi Golchin showed us a beautiful job of StateManagedCollection.
However I was wondered about using multiple classes of IStateManager in one StateManagedCollection.
As you can see below:
public class MenuItemCollection : StateManagedCollection 
{

```
public MenuItem this[int index] 
{ 
    get { return (MenuItem)((IList)this)[index]; } 
} 

public int Add(MenuItem item) 
{ 
    return ((IList)this).Add(item); 
} 

public void Remove(MenuItem item) 
{ 
    ((IList)this).Remove(item); 
} 

// Write Insert and RemoveAt methods 

protected override void SetDirtyObject(object o) 
{ 
    ((MenuItem)o).SetDirty(); 
}
```

} 
This MenuItemCollection class can have only one child class("MenuItem").
If I want to use another class as well as MenuItem class, for example MenuItem2 class, how do I have to write the codes?
Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a generic version - for example,

```
public class GenericStateManagedCollection<T> : StateManagedCollection 
   where T: IStateManager, new()
{

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return (T)((IList)this)[index]; }
    }

    public int Add(T item)
    {
        return ((IList)this).Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        ((IList)this).Remove(item);
    }

    // Write Insert and RemoveAt methods

    protected override void SetDirtyObject(object o)
    {
        ((T)o).SetDirty();
    }

    protected override object CreateKnownType(int index)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    protected override Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
        return new Type[] { typeof(T) };
    }

}
```

And use it as

```
public class MenuItemCollection : GenericStateManagedCollection<MenuItem> { }
public class XyzItemCollection : GenericStateManagedCollection<XyzItem> { }
```

**EDIT**:

I have most probably mis-understood your question! Assuming now that you want to put two different type of objects into the `StateManagedCollection`. From usage perspective, it doesn't make sense to have objects of completely unrelated types into the collection - you need to have some base class. For example, consider [DataControlFieldCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.aspx) which holds instances of (abstract) type 'DataControField`. BoundField, ButtonField etc inherits from`DataControField`.

So you need to go via similar route - for example,

```
public class MenuItemBase : IStateManager
{
   // Use implementation from link you quoted (Mehdi Golchin's answer)
   ...
}

public class MenuItem : MenuItemBase
{
  ...
}

public class MenuItem2 : MenuItemBase
{
  ...
}

public class MenuItemCollection : StateManagedCollection
{

    public MenuItemBase this[int index]
    {
        get { return (MenuItemBase)((IList)this)[index]; }
    }

    public int Add(MenuItemBaseitem)
    {
        return ((IList)this).Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(MenuItemBaseitem)
    {
        ((IList)this).Remove(item);
    }

    // Write Insert and RemoveAt methods

    protected override void SetDirtyObject(object o)
    {
        ((MenuItemBase)o).SetDirty();
    }

    // important to override CreateKnownType and GetKnownTypes
    private static readonly Type[] _knownTypes = new Type[] {typeof(MenuItem), typeof(MenuItem2) }

    protected override Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
       return _knownTypes;
    }

    protected override object CreateKnownType(int index)
    {
       switch (index)
       {
          case 0:
             return new MenuItem();

          case 1:
              return new MenuItem2();

          default:
              throw new Exception("Invalid Index");
       }
     }
}
```

Note: Untested code

Comment: @JoshuaSon, sorry - I don't have full source code. BTW, see my edit, I may have mis-understood your question!

Comment: wow...this is exactly what I wanted to find. Many thanks to VinayC.

Comment: If it's possible, may I ask you to have a look at my property problem involving this case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801103/how-to-create-available-field-properties-in-my-own-property