# How to create "Available field" properties in my own property?

Tags: asp.net

I have created a class inherit from StateManagedCollection.
It has got a few class as Columns like GridView.
But I can not select which filed I want to select from.
It should look like the picture below in design.
[image: GridView Columns property]

But mine is the one below:
[image: My GridView class's Items property]

I have written the property as below:

```
[Description("A collection of ToolBarItem's ")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public virtual Items Items
{
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView columns collection uses a custom UI Type editor to show this interface. The in-built ASP.NET `CollectionEditor` will not show the required UI. Further in your case, `CollectionEditor` may not work if the collection's item type is a abstract class.

Solution is to build your own custom [UI Type editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171838.aspx) - basic steps are

1. Inherit from `System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor`.
2. Override `GetEditStyle` method to inform the property browser that you will launch modal form.
3. Override the EditValue method to launch your custom UI form.
4. Build the custom UI Form.

See a couple examples [here](http://www.dotnetbips.com/articles/b4a11ad4-b13c-40c0-8ebe-e4f64a6ae335.aspx) (see sample for TagTypeEditor) and [here](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c3977).